# Can't avoid hibernate logging SQL to console with Spring Boot and Logback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, logback

My Spring Boot application keeps showing Hibernate queries in the console despite having configured Hibernate's specific logging with Logback as follows:

```
<appender name="HIBERNATE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGDIR}/hibernate.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGDIR}/hibernate.log.%d</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="HIBERNATE"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="HIBERNATE"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="HIBERNATE"/>
</logger>
```

It does send Hibernate's logs, including queries, to the file `hibernate.log`. But I would also like to avoid the queries in the console, which I think should be happening with this configuration.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `hibernate.show_sql` config enabled? If so, just disable it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you set the `hibernate.show_sql` to `true`, Hibernate will simply print the SQL statement to the console (not to be confused with logging under `org.hibernate.SQL`). `SqlStatementLogger` is responsible for logging the SQL statements and its `logStatement` looks like:

```
public void logStatement(String statement, Formatter formatter) {
    if ( format ) {
        if ( logToStdout || LOG.isDebugEnabled() ) {
            statement = formatter.format( statement );
        }
    }
    LOG.debug( statement );
    if ( logToStdout ) {
        System.out.println( "Hibernate: " + statement );
    }
}
```

So, if you do not want to see the queries on the console, just disable the `hibernate.show_sql` by setting it to `false` or just removing it altogether. In Spring Boot, just add this to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

Comment: didn't think it could be so simple. Thanks

Comment: LOG.isDebugEnabled() means it also controlled by logger configuration such as logback

Comment: this solution solved my problem ... more specifically the code: spring.jpa.show-sql=false

Comment: In Spring Boot, as asked, spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false is the one property that needs to be set to false as answered by Mahaveer Jangir.

Answer (score 35):

I just wanted to share that I just noticed there is another setting which could cause org.hibernate.SQL to debug in Spring Boot JUnit tests, though you might have set

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

and

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
```

...

If you set

```
debug=true
```

in your Spring application*.properties file!

This one set to true will override the show-sql setting and set it to true.

Brgds

Comment: Basically I set `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO` and which was previously DEBUG and it solved the issue

Answer (score 16):

You basically need to set 2 properties to false.

If you are using Spring boot , then set up in Application.properties as below

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
```

And If you are using hibernate.cfg.xml, then set up as below

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
```

Comment: This really works. I am fed up with `Hibernate: ...` logs. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone has tried all the above and still has issues, try setting the property:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=OFF
```

Comment: The only that worked using `Springboot 2.4.3`

Answer (score 0):

My application is a spring-boot one,

For some reason in my case the property 'spring.jpa.show-sql=false' didn't work. 
I could see the sql with the bind values keep on printing the queries in the console/log.

It is resolved by changing the root level to error like below

`<root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
 </root>`

Though we change log level to error in the root, we still can print our package/application logs in the info mode my using the separate loggers like below

`<logger name="com.application.code" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ERR_FILE"/>
    </logger>`

putting here so it might help someone.

Thanks