# How can I straighten out my Tomcat logging?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, logging

Am working on a Tomcat configuration I did not do and would like any help to fix the logging.  For reasons unknown, there are three -D parameters related to logging passed into the startup.  The process looks like:

```
./bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=CATALINA_BASE_DIR_HERE/tomcat/conf/logging.properties 
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:CATALINA_BASE_DIR_HERE/tomcat/conf/log4j.properties ...
```

The relevant section of the logging.properties file looks as shown below.  I believe this is standard.

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
...
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
```

For completeness, here is relevant portion of the log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logfile

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.logfile.File=MY_DIR/my_log.txt
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d{ABSOLUTE}] [%t] %-5p [%c] - %m%n
log4j.appender.logfile.Append=true

# per first answer given below, added:
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost] = INFO, logfile
```

Prior to today, there were no real issues - all the log data went to the log4j file as desired.  The war file deployed in this Tomcat uses Spring Data JPA and Hibernate.  To debug, `showSql` was enabled.  All the queries came out, but to the `localhost.DATE.log` file.  Can anyone tell how to fix so that ALL the statements go to the log4j designated file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `showSql` to **true**, hibernate will print SQL statement to SystemOut. You should add `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` to log4j config, so hibernate can also log the SQL statement. (The reason can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36496450))

<strike>By default, Tomcat use `java.util.logging` API for all internal logging. So the output goto `localhost.DATE.log` as you mentioned.</strike>

You can change the configuration, please refer the section [Using Log4j](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j)
(for Tomcat 6.x~8.x)

Comment: Removing the logging.properties file made those -D's go away.  But even though I added to the log4j.properties file per the reference, none of the output from Hibernate is showing up

Comment: Thinking more about it - that reference doesn't really say how to redirect SystemOut to my appender.  How would I do that?

Comment: I didn't look at the reference before trying only =INFO as that is how they were added to the localhost file.  Didn't work, so I checked the reference - that explains why =DEBUG is needed!  This worked great - thank you!