# Hibernate logging issue in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using spring boot v1.3.4 and the turned off the logging adding the below line in `application.properties`:

```
logging.level. = OFF
```

When this line is added, no debug messages are logged except `org.hibernate.SQL` messages. I am using JDNI and don't have any other hibernate configuration in the properties. Is there any reason why hibernate messages are not suppressed when the logging is turned off?

Comment: Have you tried log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF and/or change hibernate.show_sql value?

Comment: Try adding `spring.jpa.show-sql=false` to `application.properties`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496178/cant-avoid-hibernate-logging-sql-to-console-with-spring-boot-and-logback

Comment: I added spring.jpa.show-sql=false to application.properties and it didn't suppress the sql statement logging.

Comment: Adding log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF to application.properties didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

`logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=WARN` should help you.. you already know the full qualified name of the class to suppress so why don't you try it?